# Getting issue during post a answer if reputation low

Tags: support, spam

one account having reputation low get this issue during post answer but able to answer that question having more reputation same network.

> Your post cannot be submitted at this time due to the volume of spam and abuse originating from your network. We apologize for any inconvenience. See the help center for more.

Comment: Did you seen this error or did someone you know get it?  Because of the holiday weekend in the US, a definitive answer may take a few days.

Comment: Yes i have seen it in my friend account.He is unable to post a answer but i can.

Comment: User posting spam questions but i did not saw spam answer.

Comment: @Smalution There are SPAM answers, I could link you some but you would need 10'000 reputation to see them anyway, so no point in it. Anyway, if network is posting SPAM, denying it to post anything kinda makes sense. If they spammed questions and then suddenly cannot do it, but can spam answers, they probably will. Your friend got caught by side effect of actions, and that's sad, but actions makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This information about this is in the Help Center, https://drupal.stackexchange.com/help/abuse-block:

> In an effort to maintain the quality of our collaboratively edited
>   resources while imposing the fewest possible restrictions on who can
>   create and edit content, Stack Exchange utilizes several layers of
>   spam protection.
>
> While our systems are still learning to trust new users, additional
>   positing limits might be imposed if the system detects that a large
>   amount of spam or abusive content has been posted from others
>   utilizing your Internet provider in your area.

and for the particular message your friend saw:

> It means that the abuse was extremely severe, and that we
>   unfortunately can't accept your contribution until the abuse has
>   subsided. Unfortunately, in most cases, this will mean that you need
>   to contribute to the site from an alternate location until a few of
>   your contributions have been well received by the community.

Comment: Thanks @MPD, It means first he needs gain some reputation by posting form different location.